# Understanding InnoDB foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, sql, innodb

I am following one PHP & MySQL tutorial. At this point, I have to create a database that should look like this:

[image: DB Schema]

I created the databases by hand, but I do not understand the point of the roll table. For instance, let's say I want to add a movie: how am I going to do it, since I am not allowed? Example error:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`movie`, CONSTRAINT `movie_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`movieCode`) REFERENCES `roll` (`movieCode`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

I would personally do something like:

Table artist: **artistId**, firstname, lastname, nationality, dateOfBirth, otherInfo
Table movie: movieCode, title, image, category, description, **artistId**

Being the one in bold the related foreign keys. However, I do not understand the concept of using the roll table there. Can someone clarify this for me, as I'd like to do it like the tutorial pretends to teach?

DB schema I have so far:

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `artist` (
  `artistId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstName` char(30) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` char(30) NOT NULL,
  `dateOfBirth` date NOT NULL,
  `nationality` char(30) NOT NULL,
  `otherInfo` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`artistId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `movie` (
  `movieCode` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` char(30) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `category` char(50) NOT NULL,
  `movieDesc` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`movieCode`),
  UNIQUE KEY `title` (`title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `roll` (
  `movieCode` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `artistId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`movieCode`,`artistId`),
  KEY `artistId` (`artistId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `userId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstName` char(30) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` char(30) NOT NULL,
  `username` char(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` char(20) NOT NULL,
  `usertype` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;



ALTER TABLE `movie`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `movie_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`movieCode`) REFERENCES `roll` (`movieCode`) ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `roll`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `roll_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`artistId`) REFERENCES `artist` (`artistId`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Isn't it bad practice to use InnoDB? I know there are some strange behaviors with that engine.

Comment: @izuriel Not that I'm aware of, there are differences when it comes to locking. Plus you cannot use foreign key constraints in `MYISAM`

Comment: @izuriel: You're mixing up the two standard engines. InnoDB is the good one (which supports transactions and foreign keys), MyISAM is the old bad one.

Comment: @izuriel why do you think InnoDB is the default engine for mysql right now? i think you should read this http://www.oracle.com/partners/en/knowledge-zone/mysql-5-5-innodb-myisam-522945.pdf en use InnoDB from now on and never have to deal with corrupt MyISAM tables again what will happen or the nice table locking feature MyISAM has..

Comment: Yea I'm just mixing the two up, it's been a while since I used MySQL. I've been using PostgreSQL for a bit. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: In the chart above, and for those unfamiliar with what Windows 10 did to MS Access, all the graph spacing get messed up, so just imagine that the connector lines are down a little bit from where Access drew them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `roll` table (which should probably be called a *role* table) is what's known as a *many-to-many* relationship.

It stores a *link* between a movie and an artist.  Since a movie can have *many* artists, and an artist can appear in *many* movies, you need a separate table to store all those relationships.  Each row in `roll` represents an artist appearing in a movie.

To avoid any constraint errors, you would need to insert a movie and an artist in the database first, and *then* insert a row into the `roll` table to define that artist appeared in that movie.  So, the `roll` table would need two foreign key constraints; one on the `artist` table, which you have:

```
ALTER TABLE `roll`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `roll_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`artistId`) REFERENCES `artist` (`artistId`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

And another on the `movie` table:

```
ALTER TABLE `roll`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `roll_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`movieCode`) REFERENCES `movie` (`movieCode`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

With these constraints, you won't be able to define a *role* unless both that *artist* and *movie* exist.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand the logic (why to have the 'roll' table) and my dumb mistake with the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Your foreign key on movieCode should be on the roll table. MovieCode is the primary key of the movie table.

Answer (score 0):

In your given example you have to generate the foreign key constraints from the roll (role) table to the other tables (movie, artist), not the other way around.

The given error message

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`movie`, CONSTRAINT `movie_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`movieCode`) REFERENCES `roll` (`movieCode`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

implies that you have a foreign key constraint on movie which refers the roll (role) table.

This would have the semantic that only a movie can be entered for which a role (an entry in roll) exists.

But I guess the semantics should be that you can only add roles for existing movies and existings artists.
Therefore the roll (role) table should have foreign keys on the other tables, then you could add artists and movies, and then enter entries in roll (role) for valid artist-movie pairs.